# PHP override get set methods

Tags: php

Is it possible to override the get and set methods for parameters that I already have set?  So every time I set a param I have access to work with it/ validate it?

```
class User {

   public $username;

   function custom_set($name, $value) {
      if(strlen($value) < 5) {
        return "not long enough";
      } else {
        $this->$name = $value;
      }

   }  
}

$u = new User();
$u->username = "ted";
echo $u->username;
```

Outputs: "not long enough"

This is a very simplified example that I just wrote out and probably contains errors, it's just to convey what I am trying to do.

Basically everytime I call `$u->username = "anything";` I want the `custom_set` method to be called.

I don't want to do the validation in the constructor and I don't want to create separate methods like `$u->setVal("ted");`

Is this possible?

Comment: why not using a simple array for storing *parameters* and not really using real *object properties*? this way your `__set` and `__get` magic methods will always be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make those attributes `protected` or `private` then `__get` and `__set` will be called and you can delegate to whatever logic you want.

Personally, I have yet to see a case where i would consider using a `public` property for anything.

Comment: DTO. Welcome to the world of proper coding.

Comment: A DTO/VO is a proper use but I rarely see those patterns used in PHP unless you want to count internal class like `StdClass`, `SoapVar` and `SoapParam`.

Comment: And I'd say that this is sad (about rarity). People should stop mixing data storage with data manipulation and should separate these things into different objects.

Comment: Even still in the case of a VO members would not be public, they would be protected/private only allowed at assignment at construction, otherwise it would not be immutable which as I understand is a key requirement of the VO pattern. In terms of DTO thats an entirely different set of how/when usage questions, and certainly can't conform to your blanket statement of SOC WRTG storage/manipulation.

Comment: Additionally in terms of separating these things an array provided directly by the Domain Object to the storage layer for persistence is just as valid as using a DO IMO (at least in the wild west world of PHP... YMMV in other languages). Perhaps with more experience I will change my mind but not yet.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the [`__set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) method. This is called when attempted to access inaccessible properties.

```
function __set($name, $value) {
    $this->custom_set($name, $value);
}
```

Note, however, that `$username` is a public property so this will not work unless it is declared `private` or `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [Magic Methods](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/php/exploring-magic-methods-in-php-5)?

Comment: No, because those only get called for undefined attributes: "This methods get automatically called when you try to retrieves the data of undefined attributes".  I'm talking about attributes I have already defined like `$username` in the above example.